# How to make an android app that can communicate with raspberry pi via internet connection?

Tags: android, python, linux, gpio

there is something i want to ask.

Is that possible to make android app which can run/show output from raspberry pi's gpio program remotely by internet communication? I'm making a raspberry program that can detect smoke level with sensor and gpio input. I also want to know the smoke level value from the android app which communicate with raspberry pi with a very long distance internet connection. Raspberry pi will most likely act as the remote server for the android app. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use an android device to request information from your web service(which can access the data) and send in xml or json format for your device.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I onced used was via ServerSockets.

```
public class SocketServer {   
private static void handleConnection(Socket client) throws IOException {       
    Scanner in = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());        
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);        
    out.println("Connection established!");                
    String filename;        
    while (true) {           
        try {                
            filename = in.nextLine();            
            } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {               
                break;            
            }

        if(filename == "makeToast"){
                        //execute things on the RaspberryPi
                        }

        }
    }    
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException { 
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3141); 
    System.out.println("Server started!");  
    while (true) {
        Socket client = null;
        try {
            client = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection established!");
            handleConnection(client);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Connection error!");
                } finally {
                    if (client != null) { 
                        try {
                            client.close();
                            System.out.println("Connection closed!");
                            } catch (IOException e) { 

                            }     
                        }        
                    }   
        } 
    }
}
```

This is what the Receiver Programm in the Raspberry Pi embedded Java Programm looked like.

And here is the Programm from the Android Mobile Phone:

```
public class OrbControlActivity extends Activity {
private Socket socket;
private String answer;
private static final int SERVERPORT = 3141;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.100";
protected Scanner in;
protected PrintWriter out;
protected TextView text;
@Override    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_orb_control);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    text.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    new Thread(new ListenerThread()).start();
            out.println("makeToast");
}
 }


class ClientThread implements Runnable {
@Override        public void run() {
    try { 
          InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP); 
          socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);  
          in = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());   
          out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
          } catch(UnknownHostException e1) {         
              e1.printStackTrace();      
              } catch(IOException e1) {    
                  e1.printStackTrace();      
                  }    
    } 
} 
class ListenerThread implements Runnable {    
@Override        public void run() {  
    while(true) {              
        if (in != null) {          
            answer = in.nextLine();          
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {    
                @Override        
                public void run() {        
                    text.append("\n" + answer);  
                    }              
                });           
            }      
        }    
    }  
}
}
```

Notice please that there were ALOT of issues with the local IP from the Raspberry Pi. and the Router Needs to give static IPs, else this wont work